# Two identical functions but only one fires

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery script with two seemingly identical on-click handlers in two different locations. But only one gets fired when I click the respective button. Why is this?

```
var count = 0;

$("#add").click(function(){

    count++;


    $("#numberFields").append('<input type="button" id="addThisNumber'+ count +'">');

    //Handler 1
    $("#numberFields").on('click', "#addThisNumber"+count, function(){


        console.log("Handler 1" + count);

    });



});


//Handler 2
$("#numberFields").on('click', "#addThisNumber"+count, function(){


    console.log("Handler 2" + count);

});
```

Only 'Handler 1' gets called. Cannot figure out why. Both seem to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Handler 2 won't fire because it is set up on page initialization so count will equal zero and there is no #addThisNumber0 input. To fix this, you can do the following change:

```
var count = 0;

$("#add").click(function(){

    count++;


    $("#numberFields").append('<input class='addThisNumber' type="button" id="addThisNumber'+ count +'">');

    //Handler 1
    $("#numberFields").on('click', "#addThisNumber"+count, function(){


        console.log("Handler 1" + count);

    });



});


//Handler 2
$("#numberFields").on('click', ".addThisNumber", function(){


    console.log("Handler 2" + count);

});
```